# Jquery Comparison between .val() from input and variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, var

I am trying to make an input with a submit button where if I put the correct text in and press submit a div appears, if not, both the input and button turn red. Jshint says there are no problems with my code, but there seems to be because it does not work. I will paste the code below, as well as the codepen link I am working on. Any help will be very much appreciated!

The Html:

```
<input type="text" /><button>sumbit</button>
<div id="test"></div>
```

The CSS:

```
button{
  width:70px;
  height:22px;
  background:#2E9AFE;
  border: 2px solid #0489B1;
  color: white;
}

button:hover{
  width:70px;
  height:22px;
  background:#013ADF;
  border: 2px solid #0489B1;
  color: white;
}

input{
  width:170px;
  height:16px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background:#2E9AFE;
  border: 2px solid #08298A;
  color: white;
}

#test{
  width:256px;
  height:300px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: #F5D0A9;
  display: none;
}
```

And finally the javascript/JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('input').on('focus', function(){
    $(this).css({'background' : '#31B404'});
  });

  $('input').on('focusout', function(){
        $(this).css({'background' : '#2E9AFE'});
  });

  $('button').on('click', function(){
    var $a = Angusmiguel21;

    if( ($('input').val() ) == ($a) ){
      $('test').slideToggle();
    }
    else{
      $('input').css({'background' : 'red'});
      $('button').css({'background' : 'red'});
    }

  });

});
```

The problem Starts with the click on the button… Maybe this can be done with pure Javascript but I am more comfortable with JQ, but again, any help is welcome!

Here is the [CodePen Link](http://codepen.io/angus/pen/fkuAv)

Comment: What the heck is `var $a = Angusmiguel21;` supposed to do, do you have a function or variable named `Angusmiguel21` ?

Comment: I am thinking he forgot to quote it

Comment: @PatrickEvans - He probably did as he's comparing it to a string, but it seemed pretty obvious and should generate a very clear error in the console

Comment: var $a = $('Angusmiguel21'); updated that line, now on the   if/else part the else worksm the if doesnt…

Comment: Do you have an element named `Angusmiguel21`? As thats what that line is trying to do now select an element with that name. Also your slideToggle will not work as you are not using the correct selector should be: `$("#test")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the top of the file. `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

          $('input').on('focus', function(){
            $(this).css({'background' : '#31B404'});
          });

          $('input').on('focusout', function(){
                $(this).css({'background' : '#2E9AFE'});
          });

          $('button').on('click', function(){

            var a = "Angusmiguel21";

        if( ($('input').val() ) == (a) ){
              $('#test').slideToggle();
            }
            else{
              $('input').css({'background' : 'red'});
              $('button').css({'background' : 'red'});
            }

              });

        });

        </script>
```

Your variable $a should be a. Also put quotes around the value. Also it should be #test (it's an id)

Comment: Make sure you include jQuery in your file. Check my answer.

Comment: Working :D just one thing, in this line : if( ($('input').val() ) == (a) ){ , that is that "a" doing there?

Comment: "a" is the variable that holds "Angusmiguel21". jQuery variables are simply defined as var a. Instead of say PHP with $a. So a is the name of the variable.